# Método setFingerprint con libreria ZkLib ZkTeco

Tags: php

Estoy usando la documentación https://github.com/vodvud/php_zklib Hasta ahora todo bien, todo funciona muy bien, he probado agregar usuarios, conseguir eventos, borrar huella entre otros métodos. excepto la funcionalidad setFingerprint.

Lo que intento hacer el copiar la huella digital de un usuario a otra terminal ZK.

Pero por ahora intento copiar la huella de un usuario a otro pero en la misma terminal.

```
   **public function getFingerprint($uid)
    {
        return (new ZK\Fingerprint())->get($this, $uid);
    }**
```

Este método me regresa mi huella digital en la pocision 6 (el el dedo que tengo registrado), pero nose específicamente que mardar en este método:

```
$zk->setFingerprint();
```

Estuve revisando la librería y dice

```
  /**
     * Set fingerprint data array
     * TODO: Still can not set fingerprint. Need more documentation about it...
     *
     * @param integer $uid Unique ID (max 65535)
     * @param array $data Binary fingerprint data array (where key is finger ID (0-9) same like returned array from 'getFingerprint' method)
     * @return int Count of added fingerprints
     */
    public function setFingerprint($uid, array $data)
    {

        return (new ZK\Fingerprint())->set($this, $uid, $data);
    }
```

Nosé si poner setFingerprint(2,$datos);

> 2=Id $datos=Array de la funcion getFingerprint()

Al ajecutarlo no me marca ningun error pero tampoco me guarda la nueva huella.

Si alguien puede ayudarme ...

Comment: Te invito a leer [ask] y [mcve]. Tu pregunta es muy amplia y le faltan detalles. Saludos

Comment: Ya lo edité, espero sea más claro :)

Comment: Lograste resolverlo?